# CSS woes in IE6/7

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have created a [Wordpress child theme based on Thematic](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-to-the-thematic-framework-for-wordpress/) and I'm currently trying to debug the site in IE 6/7. My suspicion is that the problem is hasLayout, as that seems to be very common and the symptoms are congruent, however I have checked many of the broken elements and added hasLayout properties to those that did not already have them with no advancement.

I did have z-index set in several of the CSS classes, which I have now removed, and I'm wondering if any of you have some other suggestion about other debugging approaches.

The site is: http://032b4a6.netsolhost.com/WordPress/

I have posted here instead of the Wordpress forum as I believe my problem is more related to a standard CSS issue than anything specific to WP.

EDIT:

To detail the kind of errors I experience in IE6/7:

The header, which is an anchor with a css background property, pushes down on the search box, causing large gaps.

The nav displays as if it has an extra 75px of margin under it, causing another large gap.

The right sidebar is missing. It can be found just barely peeking from the left side of the container below the left sidebar.

The left sidebar appears to have an extra 15px of left margin, pushing it onto the main content div.

Comment: To be perfectly honest: why bother supporting version < 8? Unless you **absolutely** need to support clients/customers who refuse to upgrade, why bother? Many services are beginning to drop support for IE7 too.

Comment: Your question is very vague about what specifically is broken.

Comment: @Colin: I understand the sentiment, unfortunately Activities For Kids is an existing domain for which we have traffic data that suggests a significant number of users will be visiting the site with IE6/7

Comment: Here is a screenshot for further reference: http://i55.tinypic.com/219yq8z.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To check if a layout problem in IE6 / IE7 is hasLayout-related problems, I sometimes find it useful to use a rule like this for debugging - it's propably not something you want to use in your final stylesheet (as it will probably introduce new problems), but often it can reveal what elements needs to be given layout:

```
* {
    zoom: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of conditional comments and IE stylesheets: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Comment_CSS You need to tweak the CSS for IE and test with native IE, not browser shots.

Try taking the slider out for a minute to see if there is a CSS conflict.

And you have a few minor html errors, one having to do with an inline style sheet:
[[Invalid] Markup Validation of  032b4a6.netsolhost.com WordPress  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//032b4a6.netsolhost.com/WordPress/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.